# Windows Clustered Shared Volume IOPS

Tags: cluster, failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

Quick question. I'm reviewing the IOPS for my CSV, and im confused about the `Cluster CSVFS\Reads/sec` counter. I aligned `Physical Disk\Disk Reads/sec` (for the CSV disk) with `Cluster CSV File System\IO Reads/sec` and `Cluster CSVFS\Reads/sec`. The first two align (shows roughly the same value), but *`Cluster CSVFS\Reads/sec`* is way off the chart. Which is the real number? My assumption is that the *`Cluster CSVFS\Reads/sec`* value is inaccurate, or does not reflect disk IO (aka IOPS).

Comment: You can try running the benchmark on your CSV with fio and compare its output with metrics. It might help you identifying the accurate counter. I've been doing benchmarks and Physical disk counters showing the same numbers to fio output.

Answer (score 0):

this is the documentation from microsoft for CSV:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/cluster-shared-volume-performance-counters/ba-p/371980

your counter show empty becouse, your node isnt the coordinator.

this is practic guide to CSV counters:
https://www.techdevops.com/Article.aspx?CID=77